# How to copy some but not all of the files in a directory based on patterns in the file name?

Tags: shell, for, bioinformatics

I have a long list of files named according to the following pattern:

```
S901_S1_fastq.gz
S902_S2_fastq.gz
S903_S3_fastq.gz
S904_S4_fastq.gz
etc.
```

Because these files correspond to different experimental treatments, I want to separate them into directories for each treatment. Is there a way to move say the 300 files numbered
`S905_S5_fasta.gz` . . . `S1205_S305_fasta.gz` into a new directory?

I've tried using the `for` loop below to do this, but it has not worked:

```
for i in 'seq 905 1205'; do
  scp S${i}* Target_directory
done
```

The results of this loop are as follows:

```
cp: cannot stat 'Sseq': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '905': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '1205*': No such file or directory
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You have the wrong quotes; `'seq 905 1203'` is just that static string of 14 characters. To run the `seq` command, you need `$(seq 905 1205)` or the equivalent legacy backticks (ASCII 96) which are hard to type in a comment because they are used for controlling formatting.

Comment: ... and the lack of quoting around `"S$i"*` causes further havoc. You'll also need to quote the target directory if it contains shell metacharacters like spaces etc, or backslash-escape them.

Comment: What exactly works also depends on which shell you are using; if you are on Bash or Ksh, you could perhaps enable `extglob` and copy with a single wildcard.

Comment: This syntax works: for i in $(seq 905 1205); do scp "S$i"* Target ; done  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a shell such as `bash` that understands brace expansions you may be able to enumerate the files directly:

```
# S905_S5_fasta.gz to S1205_S305_fasta.gz
mkdir new_directory
mv S{905..1205}_* new_directory
```

Comment: OP asked for coping, not moving files, so because of complete linux beginners maybe it's better to put `cp` or `scp` instead of `mv` command in your last line.

Comment: @Damir, the OP asked for moving in the question text (where I looked) but copying in the question title (which I skipped)

Comment: @Damir `cp` I can understand, but you wouldn't use `scp` to copy files in the local filesystem

Comment: you are right, I actually missed the part that you catched :) "Is there a way to *move* ...". Regarding `scp`, I saw OP used it in his for-loop so I thought maybe he has some good reason for that, I don't know... Even `scp` can be used to copy locally (the same syntax as cp), I agree with you, man page is clear "*scp copies files between hosts on a network*".

Comment: Using your mv suggestion works, thank you!

Comment: @ClaytonTracey if an answer solves your problem please accept it with the tick mark (and maybe even upvote it). That's how you can show thanks on StackExchange sites